# Closing a pup up page after editing

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik

Hi I am still very junior so I would like to apologise in advance if my question is not straight forward.

I have a page with a button to edit the records from a Radgrid and a pop up page will be opened on a RadWindow for editing, so now I am trying to close the popup page once I am done and refresh the parent page, I have tried window.close() but it is not working on certain browsers like IE.

I am using c#. I will be happy if anyone can help me with the code for closing the pop up page that will work in all browsers and refreshing the Radgrid on a parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get a solution, I used a javascript code.
Also calling the refreshGrid function from the parent page.

```js
//Added on the popup for close and refresh
function GetRadWindow() {
            var oWindow = null;
            if (window.radWindow) oWindow = window.radWindow;
            else if (window.frameElement.radWindow) oWindow =        window.frameElement.radWindow;
            return oWindow;
        }

        function Close() {
            GetRadWindow().close();
            GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.refreshGrid();
        }

//This goes to the parent page

function refreshGrid() {
            $find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("Rebind");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are You trying to achieve is well, quite weird, but ok :P

If You will look at the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close), than You can see (at the bottom, under compatibility table) a info which is not part of any specification, but as far as I know, most browsers apply it. Basically, You can't close a page with script, if You haven't opened it with script.

So I would suggest You to open the edit page from your 'mother' page, keep a reference to newly opened tab, and trigger close when You will receive some event which will tell You that editing is completed.

But to be honest, It's quite bad idea to edit stuff in separate page. I would suggest You to simple use some modal dialog or redirection.

Comment: Thank you, what you are saying makes sense, I will try other possible ways to achieve this. Do you know how can I refresh my radgrid after editing.